# Python,float divide float and assign to a list,the value will cut off?

Tags: python, floating-point

This is a Recommend System:

In Python,I input :
1.081743 / 0.540871
The result is :  2.0000018488696933
That's correct.

But in the program:
The result is : 2.0

The Python code is as follows:

```
def getRecommendations(prefs, person, n = 50, k = 5, similarity = sim_cosine):
    totals = {}
    simSums = {}
    sims = topMatches(prefs, person, n, similarity) 
    print("Neigh: " +str(sims) + "\n")
    for item in sims:
        other = item[1]
        for i in prefs[other]:
            if i not in filterKeys:
                if i not in prefs[person] or prefs[person][i] == 0 :
                    totals.setdefault(i,0)
                    totals[i] += prefs[other][i] * item[0]
                    simSums.setdefault(i,0)
                    simSums[i] += item[0]

    rankings = []
    for item,total in totals.items():
        if simSums[item] == 0 : continue
        print("Person: %s, Total :%f , simSum :%f, Item: %s" %(person, total,  
    simSums[item], item))
```

**I append a float and string list into rankings here**

```
    rankings.append([float(total / (simSums[item] * 1.0)), item])



    print("\nRankings Before Sort:")
    print(rankings)
    rankings.sort()
    rankings.reverse()
    print("\nRankings After Sort:")
    print(rankings)
    print("***************************************************************\n")
    return rankings[0:k]
```

The Result is as follows:

---

Neigh: [(0.5408713866765542, '3'), (0.510809444238797, '7')]

Person: 2, Total :2.163486 , simSum :0.540871, Item: 1

Person: 2, Total :1.081743 , simSum :0.540871, Item: 2

Person: 2, Total :1.021619 , simSum :0.510809, Item: 7

Rankings Before Sort:
[[4.0, '1'], [2.0, '2'], [2.0, '7']]

Rankings After Sort:
[[4.0, '1'], [2.0, '7'], [2.0, '2']]

Actually,
1.081743 / 0.540871 = 2.0000018488696933
1.021619 / 0.510809 = 2.0000019576788977
But when I append to list,it will be cut off to 2.0

In this code:

```
rankings = []

total = 1.081743
sim = 0.540871

rankings.append([total / sim,'ttt'])
print(rankings)
```

The Result is OK:
[[2.0000018488696933, 'ttt']]

Here's another data

---

Neigh: [(0.5204800389058843, '3'), (0.510809444238797, '2')]

Person: 7, Total :2.081920 , simSum :0.520480, Item: 1

Person: 7, Total :4.115487 , simSum :1.031289, Item: 9

Person: 7, Total :1.040960 , simSum :0.520480, Item: 2

Person: 7, Total :2.043238 , simSum :0.510809, Item: 10

Rankings Before Sort:
[[4.0, '1'], [3.9906228126775822, '9'], [2.0, '2'], [4.0, '10']]

Rankings After Sort:
[[4.0, '10'], [4.0, '1'], [3.9906228126775822, '9'], [2.0, '2']]

---

I think there's nothing with format string
Why???

Sorry for my poor English

Comment: `The Result is as follows:` ??

Answer (score 2):

The issue has nothing to do with a loss of precision when assigning values, but rather with the fact that numbers are displayed in Python with a default precision of 6.  Note:

```
>>> x = 1.081743 / 0.540871
>>> x
2.0000018488696933
>>> "%f" % x
'2.000002'
```

To show more precision, add a width and precision to your format string

```
>>> "%21.19f" % x
'2.0000018488696933439'
```

Now if indeed 1.081743 and 0.540871 are truly your values, you won't have any trouble assigning them:

```
>>> total = 1.081743
>>> sum = 0.540871
>>> rankings = []
>>> rankings.append([float(total/sum), 'ttt'])
>>> rankings
[[2.0000018488696933, 'ttt']]
>>> rankings.sort()
>>> rankings
[[2.0000018488696933, 'ttt']]
```

BUT here is the real problem.  You *claim* to be using these values:

```
Person: 2, Total :2.163486 , simSum :0.540871, Item: 1
Person: 2, Total :1.081743 , simSum :0.540871, Item: 2
Person: 2, Total :1.021619 , simSum :0.510809, Item: 7
```

and you probably expect to see values like this:

```
>>> 2.163486 / 0.540871
4.000003697739387
>>> 1.081743 / 0.540871
2.0000018488696933
>>> 1.021619 / 0.510809
2.0000019576788977
```

but what you are really seeing are 4.0, 2.0, and 2.0.  Why is this?  The reason is that **the values you are showing are already rounded to six decimal places and therefore are NOT the actual values you are computing with!**

So you are not really dividing `1.081743 / 0.540871` because _those two numbers are approximations to the actual values you are dividing`.  And the ratio of the two actual numbers is exactly 2.0.  That's why you are seeing 2.0.

I'll try to make it even clearer.  Please study this script.  It shows what you did.  You took two perfectly good numbers then you rounded them to six fractional digits and tried to compute with them and you found a different quotient.

```
>>> total = 1.0817427733531084
>>> sim = 0.5408713866765542
>>> total / sim
2.0
>>> print "%f" % total 
1.081743
>>> print "%f" % sim
0.540871
>>> 1.081743 / 0.540871
2.0000018488696933
```

Comment: So you're saying the value of `rankings` is okay, but the sorting is causing a problem?

Comment: rankings is not okay,I mean [[4.0, '1'], [2.0, '2'], [2.0, '7']] should be  [[4.0, '1'], [2.0000018488696933, '2'], [2.0000019576788977 , '7']]

Comment: I see.  Actually that's not the case, you should indeed be seeing 2.0. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I got it,That's very kind of u!!Thanks!    But I have another question,please help me.That's I use Python and my friend uses C++ to run recommendation algorithm.The results are close when the data is small.But when I program big data,the results are quite different. So I think whether it due to float calculation?Such as float precision? Because my friend recommends item '2' and '1'

Comment: I'm regret that it isn't work...I use  print("%0.15f" % (rankings[1][0])) to print data, but it also shows 2.000000000000000

Comment: It is _supposed_ to print 2.000000000000000, because remember your rankings array was computed by dividing two numbers that were exactly a factor of 2 apart.